# Webscraping images in r and saving them into a zip file

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-analysis

I am trying to webscrape information from this website: https://www.nea.gov.sg/weather/rain-areas and download the 240km radar scans between 2022-07-31 01:00:00 (am) and 2022-07-31 03:00:00 (am) at five-minute intervals, inclusive of end points. Save the images to a zip file.

Edit: Is there a way to do it with just rvest and avoiding the usage of for loops?

I've fount out that the image address can be acquired by clicking on the image and selecting copy image address. An example :https://www.nea.gov.sg/docs/default-source/rain-area-240km/dpsri_240km_2022091920000000dBR.dpsri.png

I've noted that the string of numbers would represent the date and time. So the one I'd need would be 20220731xxxxxxx where x would be the time. However, how would I then use this to webscrape?

Could someone provide some guidance? I can't even seem to find the radar scans for that day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following code to save the screenshots of the webpage :

```
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://www.nea.gov.sg/weather/rain-areas"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Elem <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="rain-area-slider"]/div/button')
web_Elem$clickElement()

for(i in 1 : 10)
{
  print(i)
  Sys.sleep(1)
  path_To_File <- paste0("C:/file", i, ".png")
  remDr$screenshot(display = FALSE, useViewer = TRUE, file = path_To_File)
}
```

Comment: This is really a great answer! Two comments, however: (i) you do not use the `rvest` package at all so there's really no need to load it. (ii) it requires docker, which the OP may not be familiar with. He/she could more simply have firefox installed on their computer which is definitely a lower hanging fruit.

Comment: HAHA while I do not use Firefox, you are right about the point where I am not familiar with docker. In the fourth line of the code, it says standalone-firefox. Does this mean that it has to be from Firefox? Is there a way to do this without docker?

Comment: Is there a way to do it with just rvest?

Comment: when I ran this code, I got an error: Error in shell("docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox") : 
  could not find function "shell"

Comment: shell is a base R function. It should be avaible in R. Also, you need to install Docker to make this code run. You could also use google chrome with chrome driver. From my point of view, we need to use Selenium, because we need to click on the button to get all the different images.

Comment: @user19825372 (i) Actually, you can use it with Chrome as well, but it can sometimes be a pain to set up with RSelenium. I suggest you install firefox.
(ii) Unfortunately not. Your scraping task requires some interaction with the webpage so you cannot use rvest only. You will definitely need to use RSelenium.
(iii) You can replace shell() with system()

Comment: I'm preparing an answer for you which will be like a step by step guide. But the answer from @EmmanuelHamel is a great one if you have all the tools in it.

Comment: noted! thanks for all your help guys! It's my first time webscraping!

Comment: @SavedByJESUS will wait for your answer as well! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, i tried to download docker but it says that docker is not available in my version of R

Comment: @user19825372 I am in the process of writing a short tutorial for you as an answer. You'll get it soon. Also, docker is an entirely different technology, which you need to install on your system. If you don't understand how it works, you may find it difficult to use, but I guarantee that spending some time to learn it in the future will definitely benefit you: https://www.docker.com/

Comment: @SavedByJESUS, I currently use Chrome for my scraping activities. are there any important benefits which might convince me to switch to docker?

Comment: @Frodo Docker is not a technology which is specifically meant for scraping the web. Emmanuel Hamel used it just as a way to get access to firefox. It would be difficult to explain what docker is in a few sentences so I encourage you to watch this video instead if you are interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dfLOzuIg2o

Answer (score 1):

Scraping the images from the website requires you to interact with the website (e.g. clicks), so we will use the `RSelenium` package for the task. You will also need to have Firefox installed on your system to be able to follow this solution.

#### 1. Load packages

We will begin by loading our packages of interest:

```
# Load packages ----
pacman::p_load(
  httr,
  png,
  purrr,
  RSelenium,
  rvest,
  servr
)
```

#### 2. Setup

Now, we need to start the Selenium server with firefox. The following code will start a firefox instance. Run it and wait for firefox to launch:

```
# Start Selenium driver with firefox ----
rsd <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = random_port())
```

Now that the firefox browser (aka the client) is up, we want to be able to manipulate it with our code. So, let's create a variable (`cl` for client) that will represent it. We will use the variable to perform all the actions we need:

```
cl <- rsd$client
```

The first action we want to perform is to navigate to the website. Once you run the code, notice how Firefox goes to the website as a response to you running your R code:

```
# Navigate to the webpage ----
cl$navigate(url = "https://www.nea.gov.sg/weather/rain-areas")
```

#### Let's get scraping

Now we're going to begin the actual scraping! @EmmanuelHamel took the clever approach of simply clicking on the "play" button in order to launch the automatic "slideshow". He then took a screenshot of the webpage every second in order to capture the changes in the image. The approach I use is somewhat different.

In the code below, I identify the 13 steps of the slideshow (along the horizontal green bar) and I click on each "step" one after the other. After clicking on a step, I get the URL of the image, then I click on the other step... all the way to the 13th step.

Here I get the HTML element for each step:

```
# Get the selector for each of the 13 steps
rail_steps <- cl$findElements(using = "css", value = "div.vue-slider-mark")[1:13]
```

Then, I click on each element and get the image URL at each step. After you run this code, check how your code manipulates the webpage on the firefox instance, isn't that cool?

```
img_urls <- map_chr(rail_steps, function(step){
    
  cl$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = step)
  cl$click()
  
  img_el <- cl$findElement(using = "css", value = "#rain_overlay")
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  imcg_url <- 
    img_el$getElementAttribute(attrName = "src")[[1]]
  
})
```

Finally, I create an image folder `img` where I download and save the images:

```
# Create an image folder then download all images in it ----

dir.create("img")

walk(img_urls, function(img_url){
  GET(url = img_url) |>
    content() |>
    writePNG(target = paste0("img/", basename(img_url)))
})
```

#### Important

The downloaded images do not contain the background map on the webpage... only the points! You can download the background map then lay the points on top of it (using an image processing software for example). Here is how to download the background map:

```
# Download the background map----
GET(url = "https://www.nea.gov.sg/assets/images/map/base-853.png") |>
  content() |>
  writePNG(target = "base_image.png")
```

If you want to combine the images programmatically, you may want to look into the `magick` package in R.

Comment: Hi! its not a necessity for the server to be Firefox right? I can change it to chrome, safari accordingly?

Comment: @user19825372 You may have missed my comment about it on the other thread. You can use Chrome but setting it up with RSelenium can be a bit difficult sometimes. See this link for example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/09/webscraping-dynamic-websites-with-r/